# How can I make calendar notifications show bigger?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion

This seems like an easy thing but I'm coming mainly from the Win world to Mac.  Is there a way I can make notification alerts bigger? Or install a different App that will do this?

Right now if I notice them, I see a little alert boxes in the upper right of the desktop when a calendar appointment comes up.  I have no sound...and might not be sitting at the desk anyhow...so if I have a lot of windows up and happen not to look at the upper right (actually of two screens)...I just miss the notification.  I'd like to have a lot of control over those pop ups.  Size, perhaps different actions (flash the screen until acknowledged?) etc.  At the very least it's just not useful to me at all unless I can increase the size of the popups somehow.  Jack up the font size?  Again, maybe some different app that I need?  Etc.

Thanks in advance!  Man I can't seem to hit on the magic Google input to return anything useful on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, amazingly it seems there is no way to customize OS X native notification display.  The best I have come up with, in theory but not personally tested, is to add a third party notification app called Growl which is much more customizable, and then add an app that produces Growl notifications based on iCal entries.  I haven't done this yet because it seems like a lot of hassle and overkill...so for now I've been living with the native notifications.  When I have time I'll try the Growl route...unless I see something different posted here.